# why default initialization using parentheses is not permissible in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, uniform-initialization

This is the example from Effective modern c++.

```
class Widget {
…
private:
int x{ 0 }; // fine, x's default value is 0
int y = 0; // also fine
int z(0); // error!
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**direct initialization** using `()`

Inside the class treats the below
int z(0);

As a function as and expects parameter .As result error

> Expected parameter declarator

alternatively can be done

```
class Widget {
private:
    int x{ 0 };
    int y = 0;
    int z;
public:
    Widget():z(0){}
};
```

Comment: This is wrong. `std::string s("");` doesn't work here either, and `int z(0);` is correct in other contexts